# JQuery UI time slider causing some sort of mousedown error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, time, slider

I'm trying to use a JQuery UI slider to allow users to select a 24 hour time.

I'm using this code from question: [JQuery UI Slider for time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279784/jquery-ui-slider-for-time)

```
$(function() {
$(".slider_start_time").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1440,
    step: 15,
    slide: function(e, ui) {
       var hours = Math.floor(ui.value / 60);
        var minutes = ui.value - (hours * 60);

        if(hours.length  == 1) hours = '0' + hours;
        if(minutes.length == 1) minutes = '0' + minutes;

        $('#start_time_text').val(hours+':'+minutes);
    }
}); 
});
```

But I get an error: b is null???

Some sort of mousedown error when trying to drag the slider maybe?

Any help would be much apprectiated! Thanks!

Comment: I get the b is null error in firefox. Chrome gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no error on "b", here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/RYx54/.
Can you provide more code?

What kind of slider do you need to use?

```
Range
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range

With range you can capture a range of values with two drag handles. The space between the handles is filled with a different background color to indicate those values are selected.

```
Max
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemax

Fix the maximum value of the range slider so that the user can only select a minimum. Set the range option to "max."

EDIT:

the two options have different setup and use: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/RYx54/1/
the right choice depends on your needs.

Comment: I took out the range option and it started to work perfectly! No idea why!. I also used hours.toString().length instead of just hours.length

Comment: if you go to your fiddle and change the value for range from "max" to true you will see the error I was getting. Do you know why it would cause that error?

Comment: Because range true have a different use (values becomes and array) and set up, look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/RYx54/1/; it depend on your needs.

Comment: Please mark the answer if solved; if you have other problems please tell me.